# Print out the string between first two “;” in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, cut

I was wondering how can I get the string between the first two ";" with sed in Bash..

for example:

input:

```
END; startprocess -noprint; CWD: 8995; RUID: nmsadm; EUID: nmsadm;  ERRCODE: 0;
```

output:

```
startprocess -noprint
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cut` to the rescue:

```
cut -d';' -f2
```

#### Test

```
$ cut -d';' -f2 <<< "END; startprocess -noprint; CWD: 8995; RUID: nmsadm; EUID: nmsadm;  ERRCODE: 0;"
 startprocess -noprint
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up fedorqui.

Answer (score 2):

`cut` is probably the best option here but this an example of how this could be done in bash itself

```
IFS=';' read -r _ var _ <<<
'END; startprocess -noprint; CWD: 8995; RUID: nmsadm; EUID: nmsadm;  ERRCODE: 0;'
echo $var
```

Comment: I guess you missed `startprocess -noprint` output after `echo $var`. +1 for this solution.

Comment: @fedorqui, I was ticked off the other day for sticking output into my answer. So not sure if it is deemed an SO bad practice or not ;-)

Comment: Oh, that's new for me, @1_CR. I usually post the output in tags like these (bash, shell, awk, unix...) to show the exact output I am getting. It is usually helpful for everyone, even for the answerer because others can suggest better methods.

Comment: @fedorqui, good point. I shall emulate you going forward and fly in the face of critics ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is not the best solution, and you're better of with `cut` as in fedorqui's answer, but if you must:

```
$ str='END; startprocess -noprint; CWD: 8995; RUID: nmsadm; EUID: nmsadm;  ERRCODE: 0;'
$ echo "$str" | sed 's/^[^;]*;\([^;]*\);.*$/\1/'
 startprocess -noprint
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to call any external utilities. Here is a simple solution in pure [tag_bash]:

```
x='END; startprocess -noprint; CWD: 8995; RUID: nmsadm; EUID: nmsadm;  ERRCODE: 0;'
[[ $x =~ \;[^\;]+\; ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH:1:((${#BASH_REMATCH}-2))}"
```

Output:

```
 startprocess -noprint
```

Or even a more simple one:

```
x=${x#*;}; echo "${x%%;*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use awk:

```
awk -F';' '{print $2}'
```

example:

```
$ str='END; startprocess -noprint; CWD: 8995; RUID: nmsadm; EUID: nmsadm;  ERRCODE: 0;'

$ awk -F';' '{print $2}' <<< $str
 startprocess -noprint
```